# How to validate Microsoft JWT-token independent from scope?

Tags: java, validation, jwt

I am quite new in the Microsoft world. Within my Java backend I want to validate JWT token.  That is the code I use

```
public static void validateToken(
        final String pAccessToken)
{
    DecodedJWT jwt = JWT.decode(pAccessToken);

    String tenantId = null;
    String clientId = null;

    byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(jwt.getPayload());
    String payloadJson = new String(decodedBytes);

    if (payloadJson != null)
    {
        try {
            JwtTokenPayload payload = Json.mapper().readValue( payloadJson, JwtTokenPayload.class );

            if (payload != null)
            {
                tenantId = payload.getTid();
                clientId = payload.getAppid();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            ...
        }
    }

    String url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/v2.0/keys";
    if (tenantId != null && clientId != null) {
        url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenantId + "/discovery/keys?appid=" + clientId;
    }

    try {
        final JwkProvider provider = new UrlJwkProvider(new URL(url));

        final Jwk jwk = provider.get(jwt.getKeyId());
        final Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.RSA256((RSAPublicKey) jwk.getPublicKey(), null);
        
        algorithm.verify(jwt);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            ...
        } catch (JwkException e) {
            ...
        } catch(SignatureVerificationException e) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

For tokens from authentication with scope <client_id>/.default everything is fine.

But I also have tokens from authentication with scope https://graph.microsoft.com/.default. The validation runs in a SignatureVerificationException. I have read somewhere that it is not possible to validate such tokens. Is that right? Or is it possible to do it? How can I determine what kind of token I have  to decide, if I can validate it or not?

Thanks for you help and hints.